# Modify a TextView from multiple classes frequently

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I'm looking to make my own debug Activity and then update it from various other classes (not just a single class like the other questions I've seen here) using THE LEAST amount of code in my other classes. So ex:

```
// activity class
public class DebugActivity extends Activity {
public TextView txtView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
}

public someMethod(String text) {
  //Update text view code here.

}

// A class updating the text view
public class Some other class {

    someOtherMethod {

        DebugActivity.someMethod(updatedTextViewSTring);
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that i can think of is by sending the data (text) to your `DebugActivity`. You need to use this code in **each** `activity` that work with `DebugActivity`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DebugActivity.class);
i.putExtra("text", "some text");
startActivity(i);
```

And accept that data(text) in the `onCreate` of `DebugActivity` :

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b!=null)
   String text = b.getString("text");
```

Note : Theres **no** use to change the `textview` in an `Activity` in realtime because only one `activity` is displayed at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the DebugActivity will be real time and I'm really trying to keep from using more then one line because there will be so many debug calls.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant way to do is use EventBus lib https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

you need to write code like below in DebugActivity

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
public void onEventMainThread(TextEvent textEvent)
{
    txtView.setText(textEvent.getText());
}
```

after that you can send textevent from anywhere in App like below

```
eventBus.post(new TextEvent("my Message"));
```

**Or**

Pure Android way is use Broadcast / Handler

Comment: Can you give me an example using Broadcast / Handler?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use broadcast 
An activity that watches for notifications for the event named "custom-event-name".

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event-name".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};
```

And here is how you will send message from anywere in app

```
// Send an Intent with an action named "custom-event-name". The Intent sent should 
// be received by the ReceiverActivity.
private void sendMessage() 
{
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```